# Get more than one metrics using single aws cloud-watch command CLI?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

How to get the multiple RDS metrices in one CLI command instead of executing various commands?

Example:

I need CPU utilization, FreeStorageSpace, and FreeableMemory stats in single call cli

I used:

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace AWS/RDS \
     --metric-name FreeStorageSpace \
     --start-time $START \
     --end-time $END \
     --period 360 \
     --statistics Average \
     --dimensions "Name=DBInstanceIdentifier,Value=$Instance_ID"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-data --cli-input-json file://input.json
```

Where input.json contains all the relavant namespaces and metric names you would like to query.

sample input.json

```
{
    "MetricDataQueries": [{
            "Id": "cpuUtilization",
            "MetricStat": {
                "Metric": {
                    "Namespace": "AWS/EC2",
                    "MetricName": "CPUUtilization",
                    "Dimensions": [{
                        "Name": "InstanceId",
                        "Value": "i-000000"
                    }]
                },
                "Period": 60,
                "Stat": "Average"
            },
            "ReturnData": true
        },
        {
            "Id": "networkPacketsOut",
            "MetricStat": {
                "Metric": {
                    "Namespace": "AWS/EC2",
                    "MetricName": "NetworkPacketsOut",
                    "Dimensions": [{
                        "Name": "InstanceId",
                        "Value": "i-000000"
                    }]
                },
                "Period": 60,
                "Stat": "Average"
            },
            "ReturnData": true
        }
    ],
    "StartTime": "2022-04-01T00:00:00",
    "EndTime": "2022-04-30T00:00:00"
}
```

Sample Output

```
{
    "MetricDataResults": [{
            "Id": "cpuUtilization",
            "Label": "CPUUtilization",
            "Timestamps": [
                "2022-04-20T01:07:00+00:00",
                "2022-04-20T01:02:00+00:00",
                "2022-04-20T00:57:00+00:00"
            ],
            "Values": [
                0.09945355191256719,
                0.13280540890988418,
                0.13450128228466757
            ],
            "StatusCode": "Complete"
        },
        {
            "Id": "networkPacketsOut",
            "Label": "NetworkPacketsOut",
            "Timestamps": [
                "2022-04-20T01:07:00+00:00",
                "2022-04-20T01:02:00+00:00",
                "2022-04-20T00:57:00+00:00"
            ],
            "Values": [
                82.4,
                86.6,
                82.2
            ],
            "StatusCode": "Complete"
        }
    ],
    "Messages": []
}
```

I have tested with **AWS/EC2** because i don't have RDS in my account .You can very well use this and replace name space for RDS

Comment: It doesn't show the values of the metrics

Comment: I have edited my answer with details and output hope that helps